# How to extend this jQuery function

Tags: jquery

I want to extend this function and make my own, this new function should have same functions as the old one but additionalOkClicked should be overwritten with my own function.

How do I do this?

```
   (function ($) {
    $.LocationDialog = {
        mainInit: function()
        {
            //some code here
        },

        init: function(callingNum)
        {
            //some code here
        },

        additionalOkClicked: function()
        {
            //i want to override this function
        }
    };
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: Why don't you just delete the code instead `additionalOkClicked` and write your own ?

Comment: I need to EXTEND this function to override a method inside not to create new or edit the same function. I need extending cause old will be used the same but new function will be used in special case

Answer (score 1):

can't you just do:

```
$.LocationDialog.myAdditionalOnClick = function()
{
    this.additionalOnClick(); //call the other method in the object.
}
```

if y our talking about the function being bound to an event then use:

```
$('#foo').unbind('click',$.LocationDialog.additionalOnClick);
$('#foo').bind('click',$.LocationDialog.myAdditionalOnClick);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use prototype:

```
$.locationDialog.prototype.functionName = function() {
    // Your code here
}
```

or

```
$.locationDialog.additionalOkClicked.prototype.functionName = function() {
    // Code here
}
```

or just create another function inside of $.locationDialog:

```
   (function ($) {
    $.LocationDialog = {
        mainInit: function()
        {
            //some code here
        },

        init: function(callingNum)
        {
            //some code here
        },

        additionalOkClicked: function()
        {
            //some code here
        }

        functionName: function() {
            // Your code here
        }
    };
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: I need to EXTEND this function to override a method inside not to create new or edit the same function. I need extending. Prototype will change existing method, so old function won't work as expected, i need both cases.

Comment: @dfilkovi the prototype syntax that Shaz mentioned first should work then.

Comment: No it won't work cause old function will be changed and if someone want's to use previous $.LocationDialog it will be with new function, I need new $.LocationDialogExtended with new function, I don't want to change old function.

Comment: and it should be `var functionName = function() {`

Answer (score 0):

You can just add code to delete that function and then create your own with the same name:

```
(function ($) {
  delete $.LocationDialog.additionalOkClicked;

  $.LocationDialog.additionalOkClicked = function () {
    // your code here
  };
})(jQuery);
```

The rest of `$.LocationDialog` object will remain the same.